# Multilevel navigation in data-table including details and actions

Tags: navigation, data-tables, actions, contextual-menu

I have multiple interactions from one screen to another and from that screen to the next screen. At least 4 levels of navigation happens in one use case.

#### Example

User lands on the **data table** which has many columns and multiple rows with pagination.
Now the user will click on one row and gets into *details* of that row and perform a particular *action* where the user might open different popups and confirm the action.

#### Current Approach

Currently, I have opened up the **popup** with details and performing actions.
But I am not confident about this approach.

#### Main goal

The user should **not lose the context** from the *main screen* when performing the action.

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: hey there. it would help to answer your question if you could you share how your design looks

Comment: A breadcrumb trail ?

Comment: https://medium.com/nextux/design-better-data-tables-4ecc99d23356

Answer (score 1):

Your options are

1. Open the details in a separate page (big loss of context)
2. Open the details in a popup (medium loss of context)
3. Open the details inline in the table as part o the row (low loss of context)

So you already have a good way to keep the user in the context. I don't know if it is feasible to show your details and actions inline in the table row.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys for your quick suggestions. I finally used popup which was actually keeping context to the user and the plan is to do a usability test now with users and see the reactions.